# C++ Nested class is producing undefined references to outer class

Tags: c++, nested, nested-class

I have read the other threads regarding this same problem but I still don't know why I am getting the following error: `undefinded reference to` and lists every method in the outer class.

```
class ClientConnection
{

public:

   class Connector

   {

   public:

         Connector(ClientConnection&);
         ~Connector();

        void Connect(unsigned int usleep);
        void Stop();
        bool isConnected();

    private:

        void attempt();

        ClientConnection& m_client;
        unsigned int m_usleep;
        bool m_stopRequest;
        bool m_isBusy;
        boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> m_thread;

  };

  Connector* Connector();

  bool connect();
  bool isConnected();

private:

 friend class Connector;
};
```

I have a reference to the outer class. The Connector method news up a Connector object and passes it a references to itself.  But everywhere in code where I get an `undefined reference to ClientConnection::connect` and `undefined reference to ClientConnection::isConnected`.

I am completely stuck.

ALSO - when I use Connector() to new up an object, `ClientConnection::Connector* connector = client.Connector();` where client is an solid object of ClientConnection, I get `invalid use of non-static member function ‘ClientConnection::Connector* ClientConnection::Connector()’`

Comment: Where is `bool isConnected();` implemented?

Comment: You should post the constructor for ClientConnection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to consider:

1. `Connector* Connector();` - what are you trying to do here?  If you're trying to declare a pointer to a connector, do `Connector* ptr_connector;` or something.  You're basically invoking a constructor, declaring a pointer, and giving neither a variable name - it's crazy!
2. Did you actually implement the functions were seeing in the nested class, if not that's where your problem is!  Also, did you implement them correctly for a nested class? The syntax is a little different if you're not implementing them inline in the class.
3. `ClientConnection::Connector* connector = client.Connector();` - This doesn't work either.    you declared an explicit constructor in your class requiring a client connection object.  But here, you're trying to create a connector without passing any client object.  You don't have a constructor for Connector taking no parameters.

Comment: Comment 1/3: That fixed it. It was obviously the default constructor name for Connector so I renamed it to newConnector() and it now works. BTW that function does `new ClientConnection::Connector(*this)`.  One question though? The Connector() is the constructor for the Connector class but it is not in the scope of that class, it is in the scope of ClientConnection. Shouldn't it have worked?